# What are these small jets and large propeller aircraft flying in formation?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I came across the photo below on [flightaware.com](http://flightaware.com/photos/view/6917733-5c59584420ce88b0d0c06a5de54ae9fc587d0e96/staffpicksweek/sort/date/page/1). The image was taken by someone with, I think, an Ukrainian name: Arkadiusz Cieslak. They piqued my interest as they do not appear to have insignia except for the "B" (cyrillic?) on the tail of the transport plane and a design on the fighters. Any ideas? I'm just curious.

[image]

Comment: The registration of the Constellation is clearly visible (HB-RSC), and a quick google gives you all kinds of cool pictures. I'm guessing the fighters are [F-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_F-5)s

Comment: Knowing this is the livery of the [Swiss patrol](https://www.google.fr/search?q=swiss+patrol&tbm=isch) makes search easy. I like [this one](http://files.newsnetz.ch/bildlegende/93044/1158338_pic_970x641.jpg). BTW, and to link with a recent question about the carriers around the world: Switzerland [carrier](http://aviationhumor.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/swiss-aircraft-carrier.jpg) in territorial waters.

Comment: On a side note, that name (Arkadiusz Cieslak) sounds more like Polish, not Ukrainian (without actually knowing; but this kind of digraphs is typical for Polish).

Comment: I hope Mr. Cieslak will forgive me ;)

Comment: Looks like you are [in trouble](http://www.wama-sport.pl/dyscypliny/judo/17417-otwarty-puchar-juniorow-bytom-2015-arkadiusz-cieslak-postrachem-rywali).

Comment: uh oh. is there a way to change my name on SE?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The design on the belly of the fighters makes it clear that they are from the [Patrouille Suisse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrouille_Suisse), the aerobatic team of Switzerland. They use [F-5E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-5_Freedom_Fighter).

From the comment in the page you linked (or from the aircraft registration HB-RSC, as suggested by @falstro), instead, we see that the other aircraft is the Breitling (hence the "B") [Super Constellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Constellation):

> The Breitling Super Constellation from the Swiss Super Constellation Flyers Association: It is the last Super Constellation in flying condition in Europe.

Comment: Thanks Federico. I could see the Swiss livery when I enlarged the images. My old eyes are sore. David

Comment: Also, I didn't know Constellations were still in use!

Comment: @DavidDelMonte They're not still in use: the plane's essentially a museum piece.